# What is the reason of error "Not a data constructor"?

Tags: haskell

I have got an error: `Not a data constructor: "%:"`:

```
data KV = forall a. Show a => (%:) Text a
```

Interestingly, but `:%` is fine as data constructor! `%%` is not fine again. But `%%` is fine to be infix function. Why is it treating as an error? What is the difference between these variants?

Comment: How exactly do you *use* `(%:)`?

Comment: I tried `["Name1" %: var1, "Name2" %: var2]`

Comment: But I get this error in `data KV = ...` definition, not in the place where I use it

Comment: I am using `Data.Aeson`, is it possible that it exports such functions/terms? I never met them before..

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30039123/haskell-why-arent-infix-type-constructors-allowed

Comment: @AJFarmar  Ooh, this - "The caveat is that data constructors (not type constructors) must start with a colon:". Seems this is the reason

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a valid name for a data constructor. All infix operator data constructors must start with `:`. So `(:%)` would be fine.

This is just the operator equivalent of "constructors must start with capital letters", as a syntactic means to distinguish constructors from other names when pattern matching.

Comment: I memorize this as "`:` counts as an uppercase character".

Comment: I just remember that the non-empty list constructor `:` is the simplest/shortest constructor name starting with `:`.