# Arrow (->) as haskell data constructor

Tags: haskell

I'm confused about the arrow and what it actually means in the data constructor. I'm surprised it even compiled but I have no idea how to use it.

If I try to use it as the name of a data constructor it doesn't parse, and I'm not sure how else to interpret it. If I interpret it as a function type then the data constructor has no name which also does not make sense to me.

```
data Type
  = TBool
  | TInt
  | Arrow Type Type
  | (->) Type Type

test :: Type 
test = Arrow TBool TInt -- Ok

test' :: Type
test' = (->) TBool TInt -- Parse Error on input '->'
```

Comment: Are there any language extensions in use?

Comment: That is _really_ weird. I can confirm that the `data` declaration parses, but attempting to use `(->)` fails, without enabling any extensions. I suspect that the parsing algorithm has different rules in a `data` declaration than in an expression, but can’t say anything definitively.

Comment: This looks like a GHC bug to me.

Comment: Pretty sure `data Type = (->) Type Type` _shouldn't_ parse. Infix constructors must generally start with a `:`, i.e. `data Type = (:->) Type Type` would be the closest legal approximation.

Comment: I am using overloaded strings and lambda case, but I don't think that is relevant here. 
@bradrn Indeed, test' does not parse.
Should I just treat this syntax as a bug then?

Comment: @leftaroundabout I think you're right, I was looking a little bit and concluded in the same

Comment: I've submitted this as [issue #16999](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/issues/16999).

Comment: Infix constructors! Infix constructors! How did I miss infix constructors?

Answer (score 2):

It does look like a [GHC bug](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/issues/16999) (thanks to Kevin Buhr for reporting it) in the use case you provided.

**Note**

This does fail to parse with `GADTs`:

```
data Type where
  TBool :: Type
  TInt :: Type
  Arrow :: Type -> Type -> Type
  (->) :: Type -> Type -> Type
```

Comment: I doubt your hypothesis about the cause of the bug is right. See the discussion on the ticket.

Comment: @dfeuer, yep, my guess was off. In fact I still don't understand what is the reason for this bug. Nevertheless, the answer is still right, it is a ghc bug. ;)

Comment: I dunno either. Parsing Haskell is relatively hard, and parsing GHC Haskell is really hard. I personally think some of the decisions about syntax were unwise. It's pretty tricky to go back and change things in a mature language, but it looks like a few of those decisions are being reconsidered along the long road to `DependentHaskell`.

Answer (score 0):

As @leftaroundabout commented, and According to [this](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.2.1/docs/html/users_guide/data-type-extensions.html) you must add a `:` in order to create infix constructors:
And according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30039123/haskell-why-arent-infix-type-constructors-allowed):

> Unlike data constructors, infix type constructors are not allowed (other than (->)).

So by example this won't work:

```
data Type
  = TBool
  | TInt
  | Arrow Type Type
  | (-**) Type Type

test :: Type 
test = Arrow TBool TInt -- Ok

test' :: Type
test' = (-**) TBool TInt
```

but this will:

```
data Type
  = TBool
  | TInt
  | Arrow Type Type
  | (:-**) Type Type

test :: Type 
test = Arrow TBool TInt -- Ok

test' :: Type
test' = (:-**) TBool TInt
```

and this:

```
data Type
  = TBool
  | TInt
  | Arrow Type Type
  | (:-*) Type Type

test :: Type 
test = Arrow TBool TInt -- Ok

test' :: Type
test' = (:-*) TBool TInt
```

and in your case you will want something like:

```
data Type
  = TBool
  | TInt
  | Arrow Type Type
  | (:->) Type Type

test :: Type 
test = Arrow TBool TInt -- Ok

test' :: Type
test' = (:->) TBool TInt
```

Comment: Infix type constructors are allowed with the `TypeOperators` extension.